# Redux: why is action not dispatched?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am getting my head around react/redux and trying to dispatch an action in a cart application,this is part of the containercomponent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import AddProduct from './addproduct';
import Products from './products';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import * as AddActions from './actions/addaction'

const Cart = ({products, actions}) => (
    <div>
        <AddProduct addProduct={actions.addProduct}></AddProduct>
    </div>
)
```

The actions.addProduct is somehow not dispatched. This is what the AddProduct has to dispatch the action(handleAddProduct is called btw):

```
 handleAddproduct = () => {
        //does not get dispatched???:
        this.props.addProduct(this.refs.name.value);
    }
```

What am I missing here?? Here is a link to the [code](https://github.com/dimitri-a/training_cart)

Answer (score 0):

It is dispatched. You have two `cart` reducers, the store is created with the one from `./reducers/cart`, not `./components/reducers`.

Another problem is that in the reducer you have this bit of code:

```
    switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
        return [
            ...state,
            action.object
        ];
```

...and it should be `action.text` instead, because that key is created in the action creator:

```
export const addProduct  = text => ({ type: 'ADD', text })
```

That's why even though it is called, it appends `undefined` to the list in state.